# appcompat_v7 folder function

Tags: android, eclipse, android-fragments

I am creating an Android app with Eclipse and the Android SDK tools version 22.6.2.

I don't understand how to work with fragments. I have removed the default fragment layouts and now I am creating the app with normal layout files.
On Eclipse there is also a default folder called appcompat_v7 which is new for me.

The MainActivity is now as default from type ActionBarActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
```

I have changed it to Activity type after including the line:

```
import android.app.Activity;
```

And then I have changed the type to:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
```

So far all is working fine.

Now, I don't know what is the reason to keep the folder appcompat_v7. If I remove or rename it, a lot of errors appear on my app.

You are kindly requested to inform me about the function of this folder.

Comment: If you remove the library project remove the reference also and check your styles.xml for themes and change them accordingly

Comment: @Raghunandan, thank you for your comment, but I don't find any reference to this library on my styles.xml file.

Comment: Make sure you remove it from the buildpath also.

Comment: @mvasco reference to the libraay in your android project. And the styles for appcomapt must be removed. right click on your project goto properties then android then remove the reference of appcompat

Comment: @Raghunandan, OK, that works as you said, thank you.

Comment: @GrIsHu,  OK, that works as you said, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Do as follows, this works for me..**

```
Step-1:
```

Right Click on your Project -> Properties -> Android -> In Library panel, **remove** appcompat_v7 library, Apply and Ok

```
Step-2:
```

In Project goto res -> values -> style.xml

In line `<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">` **change** parent value from `Theme.AppCompat.Light` to `android:Theme.Light`

```
Step-3:
```

In Project goto res -> values-v11 -> style.xml

In line `<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">` **change** parent value from `Theme.AppCompat.Light` to `android:Theme.Holo.Light`

```
Step-4:
```

In Project goto res -> values-v14 -> style.xml

In line `<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">` **change** parent value from `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` to `android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar`

```
Step-5:
```

In Project goto menu -> main.xml **remove** these lines in menu tag:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.test.MainActivity"
```

and in item tag **change** this line from `app:showAsAction="never"` to `android:showAsAction="never"`

In project, goto res -> layout -> **delete fragment.xml**

```
Step-6:
```

In MainActivity **extends Activity** not ActionBarActivity and finally your MainActivity.java after **remove unnecessary code**, looks like this:

```
package com.example.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

**Enjoy:)**

Comment: Nice, I have followed all steps and it works like a charm, no more errors... thank you.

Answer (score 1):

appcompat_v7 is used to support ActionBarActivity and other ActionBar functions.

In latest updates SDK tools, when you create new project by default appcompat_v7 is added as a reference in your project.

If you remove this library project from eclipse then surely it will show error in your app as its referenced by your app.

To remove error you will have to follow below given steps..

Right Click on your project >> properties >> Android(see list in left panel) >> (see library panel in right bottom part of window. You will see appcompat_v7 in a list there) select that from list >> click on remove button on right >> Apply >> OK

This will remove appcompat_v7 from referenced libraries of your app and will remove errors too.